# Eclipse CDT Team Shared Index is not imported correctly when a project is imported

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I export the index of a C/C++ project into .settings/cdt-index.zip. When I import that project later, the index does not import properly. From the debug traces, I can tell that the shared index is imported with no problem, however, index is not loaded into the editor.

CDT Version: 8.6.0.201502131403

Steps To Reproduce:

1. Create a project
2. Build the index
3. Export the team-shared index to: .settings/cdt-index.zip
4. Remove the project from the Workspace
5. Re-Import the project to the Workspace

Here is the Debugging information:

```
Indexer: Removing project AttachProcessGDBTest; delete=true
Indexer: Adding new project AttachProcessGDBTest
Indexer: Setup is postponed: AttachProcessGDBTest
Indexer: Creation for project AttachProcessGDBTest
Indexer: PDOMImporter start
Indexer: PDOMImporter completed, ok=true
Indexer: Imported shared index for project AttachProcessGDBTest
Indexer: start PDOMUpdateTask
C/C++ Indexer: Project 'AttachProcessGDBTest' (0 sources, 0 headers)
Options: indexer='PDOMFastIndexer', parseAllFiles=true, unusedHeaders=useCPP, skipReferences=false, skipImplicitReferences=false, skipTypeReferences=false, skipMacroReferences=false.
Database: 475136 bytes
Timings: 7 total, 0 parser, 0 resolution, 0 index update.
Errors: 0 internal, 0 include, 0 scanner, 0 syntax errors.
Names: 0 declarations, 0 references, 0(0.00%) unresolved.
Cache[45MB]: 87 hits, 1(1.14%) misses.
Indexer: completed PDOMUpdateTask[8ms]
```

Here is the error that I get, when I try to click on a symbol:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Function 'printf' could not be resolved AttachProcessGDBTest.cpp     /AttachProcessGDBTest  line 27 Semantic Error
```

Comment: Sounds like you have found a bug, can you file it on the CDT bug tracker, that way the right people will be able to see it. https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=CDT

Comment: Here is the bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=481259

Comment: Thanks. You have contributed to making CDT an even better tool.